Home preparation for air conditioner installation
How can prepare myself for air conditioner installation when focusing on energy efficiency? Is there anything I need to know? Please help me for optimizing energy efficiency.

If your goal is optimal energy efficiency, first have an energy audit done on your home.  You don't say where you live, but many local utilities will provide a free or low-cost energy audit of your home to offer suggestions on overall house improvements and do all of their recommendations.
Then, buy the most efficient air conditioning unit you can.  This likely is a heat pump sort of installation (to provide heat in the colder times as well), and depending on your setup and location, could be air source, or ground source.
But, all of the above comes at a cost, and the highest efficiency home improvements and air conditioning units come at a higher cost than lower efficiency equipment.  So you'll need to balance your desire for energy efficiency with the cost to get to that point, both from a short term and a long term standpoint.  Some of the things you might do are practical, others not so much so, depending on cost and time to recoup your investment.
